# Target children without repeating selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to apply style `{ border: 0; padding:0; margin: 0; }` to all elements in a `<section id="contact">`

I don't want to do:

```
section#contact form { whatever style }
section#contact ul { whatever style }
section#contact p { whatever style }
```

Can I do:

```
section#contact form, ul { ... }
```

Comment: Maybe `section#contact * { whatever style }`.

Comment: could you provide even a short html + css sample?

Comment: anyway my best guess is #contact > * { whatever style }

Comment: No need to repeat `{ whatever style }`; just separate your selectors with commas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I do: `section#contact form, ul { ... }` ?

No you can't.  You need to refence the whole CSS path if you don't want the style to apply outside the `section#contact` element.

**BUT**

If you want to apply the style to all the children (and grand-children) elements, you can use the [universal selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors) :

```
section#contact * { ... }
```

If you want to apply the style only to the direct children, you can use the [direct child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) :

```
section#contact > * { ... }
```